# jQuery Datatables load data from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

im using asp.net mvc, want to load json data from server side. I have that piece of server side code:

```
Function GetData() As ActionResult

            Dim TransactionSearchRow1 = New TransactionSearchRow With {
            .status = Status.Cancelled,
            .transactinId = 12345,
            .creditCardNumber = "1234324324",
            .supplier = "Office Depot",
            .createdAt = New DateTime(2008, 12, 28),
            .amount = 500
            }

            Dim TransactionSearchRowJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TransactionSearchRow1)

            Return Json(TransactionSearchRowJson)

        End Function
```

Its just send me back json string from a TransactionSearchRow object.

I have that client-side code:

```
$("#searchBTN").on("click", function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Transaction/GetData',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#TransactionTable').dataTable({
                            data: data,
                            columns: [
                                { 'data': 'status' },
                                { 'data': 'transactinid' },
                                { 'data': 'creditcardnumber' },
                                { 'data': 'supplier' },
                                { 'data': 'createdAt' },
                                { 'data': 'amount' }
                            ]

                        });

                    }
                });
            });
```

And simple HTML table:

```
<table id="TransactionTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-md-1">Status</th>
                            <th>TransID</th>
                            <th>CCN</th>
                            <th>Supplier</th>
                            <th>Created Date</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

JSON response:
[image]

But i get an error when im click "Search" button.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Share your Json response

Comment: add it on post.

Comment: have you confirmed that `data` in the success function returns correct?

Comment: I post the data that returned.

Comment: It seems like no error in your code just ordering error. You need to set columns order according to response.

Comment: the order is correct

Answer (score 2):

I think your response data format is not right. please refrence this [example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html).The ajax response should be a object which has an array property named "data".
I'm not familiar with VB,so I give you C# code snippet.
change your server side action code like following:

```
 return Json(new {
        data: new List<TransactionSearchRow>(){TransactionSearchRow1}
    })
```

Comment: Will try it and back